# How to transfer CSV file data from a URL address to a gridview in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, csv

I am new to ASP.net web programming and I am trying to develop a web application that will transfer CSV file data to gridview in asp.net. For example I have below url:

> http://sam.sample.com/samp/DATA.CSV

Above url must be transferred in gridview using asp whenever the file has been uploaded,so meaning the date and time of uploading must be displayed also.

I have tried below codes but got an error:

```
  Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Try
        Dim cls As Class1 = New Class1()
        Dim webrequest As System.Net.HttpWebRequest
        Dim URL As String = "http://sam.sample.com/samp/DATA.CSV"
        Dim csvuri As New Uri(URL)

        webrequest = DirectCast(System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create(csvuri), System.Net.HttpWebRequest)
        webrequest.UseDefaultCredentials = True
        webrequest.PreAuthenticate = True
        webrequest.Credentials = New Net.NetworkCredential("ABC", "A123")
        If (webrequest.GetResponse().ContentLength > 0) Then
            Dim strReader As New System.IO.StreamReader(webrequest.GetResponse().GetResponseStream())

            cls.CreateCSVTable(strReader.ReadLine())

            While (InlineAssignHelper(SingleLine, strReader.ReadLine())) IsNot Nothing
                cls.AddRowCSVTable(SingleLine)
            End While
            GridView1.DataSource = cls.CSVTable
            GridView1.DataBind()

            If strReader IsNot Nothing Then
                strReader.Close()
            End If
        End If
    Catch ex As System.Net.WebException
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    End Try
End Sub

 Public Sub CreateCSVTable(ByVal TableColumnsList As String)
    CSVTable = New DataTable("CSVTable")
    Dim myDataColumn As DataColumn
    Dim ColumnName As String() = TableColumnsList.Split(",")
    For i As Integer = 0 To ColumnName.Length - 2
        myDataColumn = New DataColumn()
        myDataColumn.DataType = Type.GetType("System.String")
        myDataColumn.ColumnName = ColumnName(i)
        CSVTable.Columns.Add(myDataColumn)
    Next
End Sub

Public Sub AddRowCSVTable(ByVal RowValueList As String)
    Dim RowValue As String() = RowValueList.Split(","c)
    Dim myDataRow As DataRow
    myDataRow = CSVTable.NewRow()
    For i As Integer = 0 To RowValue.Length - 2
        myDataRow(i) = RowValue(i)
    Next
    CSVTable.Rows.Add(myDataRow)
End Sub
```

The error was "Cannot find column 0" which points on:

```
 myDataRow(i) = RowValue(i)
```

How can I resolve this error. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where is " Dim cls As Class1 = New Class1()" ?? have you checked the response from your webrequest that you have a response stream / string? The response from the url : http://sam.sample.com/samp/DATA.CSV is a 502 ? the file cant be found.

Comment: Sir the methods "CreateCSVTable" and "AddRowCSVTable" were coded in Class1. What do you mean checking the response from webrequest Sir?

Comment: Open a browser and paste the url your are pulling the http from i.e: http://sam.sample.com/samp/DATA.CSV you will see you get no response. You need a response to be able to read the data in the .csv file do you have a valid .csv file? The table creation code is not even being passed the Column headers is this copy paste from somewhere? We can help if you clarify what you are trying to do :)

Comment: Sir it's just an example URL.

Comment: I have already tried opening the original url and it opens successfully.

Comment: Can you paste some content of the .csv file you have downloaded ?

Comment: yes sir I do have a valid .csv file. I also copy paste it from somewhere. I am trying to transfer the .csv file data into gridview from that given/specific url address.

Comment: Will have a look tonight and post an update.

Comment: This one sir...                                                   AB0017 J/RAINY 15 21 17 80 ANM 7 107.7 2 4

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45235/discussion-between-laird-streak-and-j-j)

Answer (score 0):

I have created a sample solution here: [Sample Solution](https://github.com/grim93/CSVDataGridSample)

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Sir I've downloaded your uploaded solution but the version of the visual studio you have used is much higher than the version I am using that's why I can't open the file.

Comment: Sir could you save it using 2008 version of visual studio for me to open it. Thanks :-)

Comment: Ok Sir I'll wait for it.